# Why does it give me an FileNotFoundException, when the pathname is right?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, path, java.util.scanner

Why does it give me an `java.io.FileNotFound` exception?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\My docuzments\\wortliste.txt"));
```

I'm 100% sure that the pathname is right, I also imported `java.io.*`
so where could the problem be? And how can I get rid of it?

I get this error message.

```
Error:(11, 23) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
    must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

(Also: yes I have called my Documents, docuzments)

Edit:
there has to be a problem with the file, because when i copy the file and paste it into a new one, it works fine.
edit 2 : it doesnt  the scanner is the problem i think.

Final Solution! : java couldnt get the pathname, so i put the file into my project folder and just referemced the file name, this worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, can you please add the exception message

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
try
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\My docuzments/wortliste.txt"));
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

You can also first define `File f = new File(path);`
And then
call `f.exists` to check if the file does indeed exist.

Comment: the Try/catch method did not catch anything. With `f.exists` I found out that the path does exist.

Comment: What happens when you compile that code then? Do you get a error different from FileNotFound?

Comment: I get no errors anymore when I implement the try/catch

Comment: it doesn't read any words , i added some words to the list to check if the print function worked, and thats the case.

Comment: permission maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use one \ before your file name like:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\My 
docuzments\wortliste.txt"));
```

Comment: That would cause a compiler error (a different one to the warning they are currently getting).

Answer (score -1):

You need to catch the `FileNotFoundException` exception 
below the code

```
try
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\My docuzments\\wortliste.txt"));
}catch (FileNotFoundExceptione){}
```

Comment: Unless you are intending to show good practices in exception handling, please don't cover it at all. **Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`**